# System.Timer elapsed in separate thread and keeping the thread limit

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, timer, threadpool

I want to limit my number of threads in my multi-threaded WCF service. So, I use `ThreadPool.SetMaxThread` function. Now, I want to use `System.Timers` to generate events at given intervals.

But, my service receives at the meantime many actions to execute in the thread pool. When my timer is elapsed, the action is queued  in the ThreadPool (I've sometimes 100,000 tasks in expectations) and therefore slow to execute.

Is there a way to execute my elapsed event before? For example, by setting priority task queued on the threadpool? Or Elapsed the event outside of the threadpool?

I want to keep my global limit of thread in my service.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to limit threads number only to protect denial of service attacks then better option here is to limit `maxConcurrentCalls` property for `ServiceThrottlingBehavior`.
see details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.maxconcurrentcalls.aspx

By default this parameter is 16 times the processor count.

If so then you can avoid to limit max threads number for thread pool.

Then your WCF service will be safe from multiple concurrent calls point of view and at the same time timer events will be processed witn no delay.

Comment: no I don't want to limit concurrent calls but to limit number of thread in my service, because each call will be analized and runned in many thread concurrently...

Comment: There is no built-in ability in `ThreadPool` to set task priority. The similar question was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548208/how-to-call-a-method-async-with-some-kind-of-priority)

Answer (score 1):

You could, if an option, convert your code to support a producer-consumer pattern by using the `Taskfactory` combined with a blocking collection.

The collection allow you to set a max limit.

From the link below:

> ```
> - An implementation of the Producer-Consumer pattern.
>
> - Concurrent adding and taking of items from multiple threads.
> ```
>
> **>     - Optional maximum capacity.**
>
> ```
> - Insertion and removal operations that block when collection is empty or 
>   full.
>
> - Insertion and removal "try" operations that do not block or that block
>   up to a specified period of time.
>
> - Encapsulates any collection type that implements
>   IProducerConsumerCollection(Of T)
>
> - Cancellation with cancellation tokens.
>
> - Two kinds of enumeration with foreach (For Each in Visual Basic):
>
>     - Read-only enumeration.
>
>     - Enumeration that removes items as they are enumerated.
> ```

Here are some resources worth to check out:

[blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This .NET Matters MSDN article [ThreadPoolPriority, and MethodImplAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163896.aspx) is a bit old but I think the approach is still valid. His solution is to create a ThreadPriorityPool that defines what the next available thread from the managed pool should execute.

Another option is to try the [Smart Thread Pool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool) on CodeProject. It explicitly supports ordering work items by priority.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But, for your first solution, my problem is that only timer events elapsed should fire with high priority on another thread. And timer automatically start in the threadPool...