# Running a long-running parallel task in the background, while allowing small async tasks to update the foreground

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

I have around 10 000 000 tasks that each takes from 1-10 seconds to complete. I am running those tasks on a powerful server, using 50 different threads, where each thread picks the first not-done task, runs it, and repeats.

Pseudo-code:

```
for i = 0 to 50:
    run a new thread:
        while True:
            task = first available task
            if no available tasks: exit thread
            run task
```

Using this code, I can run all the tasks in parallell on any given number of threads.

In reality, the code uses C#'s Task.WhenAll, and looks like this:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = threadCount; //Allow more HTTP request simultaneously
var currentIndex = -1;
var threads = new List<Task>(); //List of threads
for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) //Generate the threads
{
    var wc = CreateWebClient();
    threads.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true) //Each thread should loop, picking the first available task, and executing it.
        {
            var index = Interlocked.Increment(ref currentIndex);
            if (index >= tasks.Count) break;
            var task = tasks[index];
            RunTask(conn, wc, task, port);
        }
    }));
}

await Task.WhenAll(threads);
```

This works just as I wanted it to, but I have a problem: since this code takes a lot of time to run, I want the user to see some progress. The progress is displayed in a colored bitmap (representing a matrix), and also takes some time to generate (a few seconds).

Therefore, I want to generate this visualization on a background thread. But this other background thread is never executed. My suspicion is that it is using the same thread pool as the parallel code, and is therefore enqueued, and will not be executed before the parallel code is actually finished. (And that's a bit too late.)

Here's an example of how I generate the progress visualization:

```
private async void Refresh_Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bitmap = await Task.Run(() => // <<< This task is never executed!
    {
        //bla, bla, various database calls, and generating a relatively large bitmap
    });

    //Convert the bitmap into a WPF image, and update the GUI
    VisualizationImage = BitmapToImageSource(bitmap);
}
```

So, how could I best solve this problem? I could create a list of `Task`s, where each `Task` represents one of my tasks, and run them with Parallel.Invoke, and pick another Thread pool (I think). But then I have to generate 10 million `Task` objects, instead of just 50 `Task` objects, running through my array of stuff to do. That sounds like it uses much more RAM than necessary. Any clever solutions to this?

EDIT:
**As Panagiotis Kanavos suggested in one of his comments, I tried replacing some of my loop logic with ActionBlock, like this:**

```
// Create an ActionBlock<int> that performs some work. 
var workerBlock = new ActionBlock<ZoneTask>(
t =>
{
    var wc = CreateWebClient(); //This probably generates some unnecessary overhead, but that's a problem I can solve later.
    RunTask(conn, wc, t, port);
},
// Specify a maximum degree of parallelism. 
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threadCount
});

foreach (var t in tasks) //Note: the objects in the tasks array are not Task objects
    workerBlock.Post(t);
workerBlock.Complete();

await workerBlock.Completion;
```

*Note: RunTask just executes a web request using the WebClient, and parses the results. It's nothing in there that can create a dead lock.*

This seems to work as the old parallelism code, except that it needs a minute or two to do the initial foreach loop to post the tasks. Is this delay really worth it?

Nevertheless, my progress task still seems to be blocked. Ignoring the Progress< T > suggestion for now, since this reduced code still suffers the same problem:

```
private async void Refresh_Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("This happens");
    var bitmap = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("This does not!");
        //Still doing some work here, so it's not optimized away.
    };

    VisualizationImage = BitmapToImageSource(bitmap);
}
```

So it still looks like new tasks are not executed as long as the parallell task is running. I even reduced the "MaxDegreeOfParallelism" from 50 to 5 (on a 24 core server) to see if Peter Ritchie's suggestion was right, but no change. Any other suggestions?

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

The issue seems to have been that I overloaded the thread pool with all my simultaneous blocking I/O calls. I replaced WebClient with HttpClient and its async-functions, and now everything seems to be working nicely.

Thanks to everyone for the great suggestions! Even though not all of them directly solved the problem, I'm sure they all improved my code. :)

Comment: i think this may give you a starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548208/how-to-call-a-method-async-with-some-kind-of-priority

Comment: .NET already has such a mechanism through `Progress< T>` and `IProgress< T> `

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. The TPL itself takes care of using threads to process a task's payload. What does `RunTask` do and why don't you just use `Task.Run` on it?

Comment: TPL has  degree of parallelism and doesn't try to do too many things at once (typically only one thing per cpu/core at a time).  If you don't have 50 cpus/cores, the TPL is likely throttling how many tasks are running at once.

Comment: Thank you, Kanavos and Ritchie. I have tried some of your suggestions, see the edit.

Comment: I created a minimal code example, which illustrates that Kanavos is indeed right; this is not normal .Net behaviour -- my task should not be blocked. (Code example: http://pastebin.com/DE0nGwUj). But I'm still puzzled. Why won't my task execute at all?

Comment: Looks to me like you're parallelizing blocking code. A lot. May I recommend using purely asynchronous I/O? That should reduce the pressure on the thread pool, which will allow code like `Task.Run` to execute sooner.

Comment: That's probably a good point, Stephen. I will look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET already provides a mechanism to report progress with the [IProgress< T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [Progress< T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation.

The IProgress interface allows clients to publish messages with the [Report(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193864(v=vs.110).aspx) class without having to worry about threading. The implementation ensures that the messages are processed in the appropriate thread, eg the UI thread. By using the simple `IProgress< T>` interface the background methods are decoupled from whoever processes the messages.

You can find more information in the [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) article. The cancellation and progress APIs aren't specific to the TPL. They can be used to simplify cancellation and reporting even for raw threads.

Progress< T> processes messages on the thread on which it was created. This can be done either by passing a processing delegate when the class is instantiated, or by subscribing to an event. Copying from the article:

```
private async void Start_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //construct Progress<T>, passing ReportProgress as the Action<T> 
    var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);
    //call async method
    int uploads=await UploadPicturesAsync(GenerateTestImages(), progressIndicator);
}
```

where `ReportProgress` is a method that accepts a parameter of int. It could also accept a complex class that reported work done, messages etc.

The asynchronous method only has to use IProgress.Report, eg:

```
async Task<int> UploadPicturesAsync(List<Image> imageList, IProgress<int> progress)
{
        int totalCount = imageList.Count;
        int processCount = await Task.Run<int>(() =>
        {
            int tempCount = 0;
            foreach (var image in imageList)
            {
                //await the processing and uploading logic here
                int processed = await UploadAndProcessAsync(image);
                if (progress != null)
                {
                    progress.Report((tempCount * 100 / totalCount));
                }
                tempCount++;
            }

            return tempCount;
        });
        return processCount;
}
```

This decouples the background method from whoever receives and processes the progress messages.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, are you sure this is a solution to my issue? I may not have been clear enough: the problem is not strictly related to progress. As long as my background parallel tasks are running, I am unable to start ANY new Tasks from the GUI. I suspect that this is related to the thread pools, but I don't know it well enough. While the Progress<T> certainly looks interesting, it looks like it still requires a Task.Run (line 4, 2nd code block) in order to work, and this Task.Run will not be able to execute while the parallell tasks are running, making it unusable.

Comment: @ErlenD. no it doesn't. If you experience blocking problems it's because the code itself blocks. Adding yet another Task.Run that ends up calling BeginInvoke for example, will still block on the UI thread. You need to **simplify** your code, removing any code added to "fix" Tasks.

Comment: @ErlenD. for example, tasks aren't threads. You *don't* need and *shouldn't* use an infinite loop to "pick tasks". That's what the TPL already does. It uses its own threads to pick up and process tasks, *without* blocking. You didn't post the code to `RunTask` though, so it's hard to say what is going wrong

Comment: @ErlenD. btw .NET already has a class to which you can post messages and have them processed, the [ActionBlock< TInput>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I tried to remove my infinite loops in favor of the ActionBlock. It gave me a slower startup (because of the loop required to post all the tasks), but still seems to have the same issue. Is it worth the slow-down? Also, I removed the progress code to prevent any potential dead locks, and added some Debug.WriteLines to further illustrate the problem. I am quite certain that the Task actually never starts, even though I reduced the parallel tasks to 5. See my newest edit in the original post for more information.

Comment: What slow-down? Neither TPL nor Actionblock has blocking or slow-down issues. Using a small number of connections though will definitely slow down everything - setting `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to a small number will definitely cause delays. You haven't posted complete code either so it's impossible to give any answer. I use Actionblock et al to send a few hundred requests and process the results. I also use HttpClient so that I *don't* have to create a new instance each time. My conneciton limit is 100 or larger and DOP as big as the server(s) can handle.

Comment: HTTP calls are inherently slow and can definitely benefit from asynchronous execution, which is another huge reason to avoid WebClient.

Comment: I meant the extra time it takes to execute this loop: foreach (var t in tasks) workerBlock.Post(t);

Comment: Sorry, I was tired after a long day of debugging. Of course that loop wasn't the reason for the slow-down, it was the check that prevented duplicates from getting into my task list. See my original question for the probable solution.