Progressbar or Data in View not shown in WPF
I'm loading a large set of data, and I want to display a ProgressBar while the data is being analyzed. Here's what I've tried so far:
                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                IsLoading = true;
                SelectedFilePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    AnalyzeHands();
                    var sortedHands = SortHandRangeComparisons();

                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        HandRangeComparisons.Clear();
                        foreach (var item in sortedHands)
                        {
                            HandRangeComparisons.Add(item);
                        }

                        IsLoading = false;
                    });
                });
            }

Currently, the ProgressBar appears, but the data isn't refreshed in the UI. When I place the AnalyzeHands method inside the Dispatcher, the data refreshes, but the ProgressBar doesn't display.
                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                IsLoading = true;
                SelectedFilePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        AnalyzeHands();
                        var sortedHands = SortHandRangeComparisons();
                        HandRangeComparisons.Clear();
                        foreach (var item in sortedHands)
                        {

                            HandRangeComparisons.Add(item);
                        }

                        IsLoading = false;
                    });
                });
            }

Where I am wrong?

You need to explain which part of your code actually updates the UI and how exactly it is supposed to do that.

You may also want to take a look at how to make use of IProgress: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42094295/1136211

@Clemens in the first examplecode the ProgressBar is shwon, but no data refreshing. In the second example no ProgressBar, but data is refreshing

Sure, you already wrote that in your question. It is however unclear where and how the UI is updated. Is it in the AnalyzeHands method? How does that code look like? Is there some kind of loop?

Sorry missunderstood it. The AnalyzeHands loads the data and analyzed them, this tkaes time. After this process the data is added to HandRangeComparisons, an ObservableCollection. This adding should update the view.

How have you specified the Progress Bar in xaml? Maybe Max Val is not in range or increment is too small? I have similar code that loads from 1M to 3M records.
